# How can I remove a specific symbol from for an entire column

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I am wondering how can I delete a specific symbol for an entire column. Here is what the original data look like: [original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1D12.png).

The only element I want to get are the first words.

Here is what my full dataset look like:

Below are data background info

```
library("dplyr")
library("stringr")
library("tidyverse")
library("ggplot2")

# load the .csv into R studio, you can do this 1 of 2 ways
#read.csv("the name of the .csv you downloaded from kaggle")
spotiify_origional <- read.csv("charts.csv")
spotiify_origional <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/info201a-au2022/project-group-1-section-aa/main/data/charts.csv")
View(spotiify_origional)
# filters down the data
# removes the track id, explicit, and duration columns
spotify_modify <- spotiify_origional %>% 
  select(name, country, date, position, streams, artists, genres = artist_genres)

#returns all the data just from 2022
#this is the data set you should you on the project
spotify_2022 <- spotify_modify %>% 
  filter(date >= "2022-01-01") %>% 
  arrange(date) %>% 
  group_by(date)

spotify_2022_global <- spotify_modify %>% 
  filter(date >= "2022-01-01") %>% 
  filter(country == "global") %>% 
  arrange(date) %>% 
  group_by(streams)
View(spotify_2022_global)
```

This is what I did,

```
top_15 <- spotify_2022_global[order(spotify_2022_global$streams, decreasing = TRUE), ]
top_15 <- top_15[1:15,]
top_15$streams <- as.numeric(top_15$streams)
View(top_15)  

top_15 <- top_15 %>% 
  separate(genres, c("genres"), sep = ',')
top_15$genres<-gsub("]","",as.character(top_15$genres))
View(top_15)
```

And now the name look like this:

[name now look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z92uM.png)

I tried use the same gsub function to remove the rest of the brackets and quotation marks, but it didn't work.

I wonder what should I do at this point? Any recommendations will be hugely help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you could do this with a combination of `sub` to remove unwanted characters with `string::word()` which is a nice thing to extract a word.

```r
w <- "[firstWord, secondWord, thirdWord]"

stringr::word(gsub('[\\[,\']', '', w),1)
#> [1] "firstWord"
```

This works also for `w <- "['firstWord', 'secondWord', 'thirdWord']"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
top_15$genres <- gsub("]|\\[|[']","",as.character(top_15$genres))
```

where the regex expression `"]|\\[|[']"` used the `|` character, OR, to match multiple things namely:

- `]` closing square bracket
- `\\[` opening square bracket
- `[']` single quotations

tidyversing up the *"This is what I did"* code, gives you:

```
spotify_2022_global %>% 
  arrange(desc(streams)) %>% 
  head(15) %>%
  mutate(streams = as.numeric(streams),
         genres = gsub("]|\\[|[']|,","",genres),  # remove brackets and quote marks
         genres = str_split(genres, ",")[[1]][1]))  # get first word from list
```

gives:
[image]